# Are there names for the smallest Gaussian prime $1+i$ (or even $1-i$)?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, definition, math-history, prime-factorization

From a recent question on putative names for the sum of the real part and the imaginary part of a complex number at SE.DSP ([Technical Term for the Sum I + Q](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/54309/15892)), I was wondering **whether there are names for the complex quantity $1+i$**, which is the smallest of the Gaussian primes. I have checked in my versions of the books:

- [André Warusfel : Les Nombres et leurs mystères](https://www.seuil.com/ouvrage/les-nombres-et-leurs-mysteres-andre-warusfel/9782757823958)
- [François Le Lionnais : Les Nombres Remarquables](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Book:Fran%C3%A7ois_Le_Lionnais/Les_Nombres_Remarquables)
- [David Wells: The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Penguin_Dictionary_of_Curious_and_Interesting_Numbers)

Since it also plays a role in definitions for Gaussian Mersenne numbers ($(1 \pm i)^n-1$ or $-i((1+i)^n-1)$), I hoped it was given a specific name in the literature, and I could not find any so far.

Comment: The Gaussian integer $1+i$ is analogous to the integer $2$: every Gaussian integer $a+bi$ is either "even" (meaning that $a+bi \equiv 0 \pmod {1+i}$, which is equivalent to $a$ and $b$ having the same parity) or "odd" (meaning that $a+bi \equiv 1 \pmod {1+i}$, which is equivalent to $a$ and $b$ having opposite parities), but not both.